# How to transform Uint8Array to .mp4 from AWS response

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Hello fellow programmers.
I'm having a problem with transforming a response from AWS S3 to a .mp4 and then loading the content to a video tag.

The script:

```
var s3 = new AWS.S3({
    endpoint: '...',
    accessKeyId: "...",
    secretAccessKey: "...",
    region: '...',
});

s3.getObject(
    {
        Bucket: "...",
        Key: "video.mp4"
    },
    function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("[VideoPlay | ERROR | fallo del get]: " + err);
        } else {
            var video = document.getElementById('video');
            var source = document.createElement('source');
            var content = new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)], { type: "video/mp4" });
            var url = (window.URL || window.webkitURL).createObjectURL(content);
            source.setAttribute('src', url);
            video.appendChild(source);
            video.play();
        }
    }
);
```

The error: 416 (Requested Range Not Satisfiable)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was uploading the file incorrectly.
Here is the "get": [get link](https://github.com/NormanPerrin/work-scripts/blob/master/aws/js/getVideo.js)

And here is the upload: [upload link](https://github.com/NormanPerrin/work-scripts/blob/master/aws/js/uploadFile.js)

Comment: Aw sad. Those links are broken now.